# How to remove /home/directory folders in bash?

Tags: shell-script

How I can delete these folders from /home/directory/ in bash?

[image]

Comment: you might user ``` userdel -r username``` corresponding to the home users you want to delete or  usr ``` rm -rf /home/REGULAREXPRESSIONFEATALLDIRECTORIESTODELETE``` or a for loop ... so many solutions....

Comment: You should not post images with text here.

Comment: Why should *those* be removed and not others? Because they're "28K" or because that's the arbitrary list of directories you want deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rm -r /home/{0,5,alojzy,...,la}
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you